# How does the new Canyon Endurace rim version support 33mm tyres with R7000 brakes?

Tags: brakes, tyre-width, clearance

Canyon just popped a new version of the Endurace [back in stock](https://www.canyon.com/en-gb/road-bikes/endurance-bikes/endurace/endurace-7/2942.html?dwvar_2942_pv_rahmenfarbe=BK) and I'm a bit confused. Half way down the page they claim "With 33 mm of clearance, just fit chunkier all-road rubber and you’re good to go." for gravel riding.

But the bike is fitted with Shimano's 105 callipers. To the best of my knowledge, these only support up to 28mm tyres. What am I missing here - are Canyon suggesting you must swap the brakes to put in wider tyres...? Or are they tacitly accepting that slightly chunkier tyres can fit inside the 105 callipers.

Comment: The funny thing is that in the "Brakes" section they state: " Shimano 105 R7000
    Dual-pivot brake caliper with predictable, precise modulation. Compatible with **28 mm tyres.**" [emphasis mine] Maybe they are just quoting the Shimano specs here. When you look at the photos you can see that the brakes are mounted relatively high, maybe they’ve found that this allows for additional clearance.

Comment: Perhaps some questionable marketing - the FRAME can clear 33mm tyres, but you'd need disk brakes to do that.  Shame its a rim brake only bike then.

Comment: 33 sounds about right for the current centerpull-in-disguise brakes when the frame/fork is built to run at the end of the slot.

Comment: I wrote an answer about how I have a bike with R7000 bikes that fits 32s, but it turns out I have R7000 for everything but the calipers, which are BR-R451 instead. I wonder if perhaps a similar situation is here, with an error on the spec sheet for Canyon.

Answer (score 9):

I talked to Canyon's support and they have clarified that apparently it's an error.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting the follow up. Good info